# Access dom element list of classes with Vue 3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to watch if a class exist in a dom element inside my component but can't figure out the way to do this inside the onMounted hook:

This a simplified version of my template:

```html
<template>
        <a
          ref="tabLink"
          href="#"
          role="tab"
          :class="{ chatUpdated: this.chatSessionId === tab.chatSessionId }"
        >
          {{ tab.title }}
        </a>
</template>
```

This is my setup function:

```
  setup() {
    const tabLink = ref(null);
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(tabLink.value["0"].classList[0]);
    });
  }
```

As you can see I'm trying to console.log the classes of my `<a>` tag in my template but I always get an undefined value. I thought that the component's DOM was already there when the onMounted hook is called so I don't get why I'm getting an undefined value.

Comment: perhaps `this.chatSessionId === tab.chatSessionId` is false `on munted` - try `console.log(this.chatSessionId === tab.chatSessionId)`  to debug your problem

Comment: @Bravo even is that conditional is not true then the console.log have to log an empty string if there's not a class in the dom element.

Answer (score 1):

The way you look for the class is wrong.

You need to:

```js
const tabLink = ref(); // remove the null from here

console.log(tabLink.value.className); // gets all the classes as string
console.log(tabLink.value.className.split(" ")); // returns an array of classes
```

Comment: When I do a console.log(tabLink.value.className) I get "undefined"

Comment: Sorry I forgot the other edit I did, you also need to use an empty `ref` instead of writing `null`. I tried in a random project and than worked. Answer edited accordingly

Comment: Thanks but still getting undefined.

Comment: just FYI I tried console.log(tabLink.value[0].className); and it worked. Thing is for some reason the class is not there when the component is mounted, so it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick):

> When you mutate reactive state in Vue, the resulting DOM updates are not applied synchronously. Instead, Vue buffers them until the "next tick" to ensure that each component updates only once no matter how many state changes you have made.

In your case, there's a class binding on the `<a>` which changes based on `chatSessionId`. That binding's effect is seen in the next tick.

#### Solution

Await a call to [`nextTick()`](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) to observe the effect:

```js
            
onMounted(async () => {
    
  await nextTick()

  // class list effect is now available
  console.log(tabLink.value[0].classList[0])
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-get-effect-on-mount?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Comment: Many thanks @tony19. Unfortunately is not working. If I edit the code and then save it I can see the log into the console and it works fine but then when I reload the page etc and the component gets mounted it will console an empty string. Which makes me think the problem is indeed asynchronicity, I just don't understand why is not working with your solution.

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?